# Datatable to array and then to a Textbox

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I have a datatable with only one column and rows with just some integers. I would like to transition them into a array so I can display them in a textbox

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: You need to turn that array of ints into a string. Try string.join...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq and `String.Join`:

```
int[] nums = table.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>(0)).ToArray();
TextBoxNums.Text = string.Join(",", nums);
```

If you want to split them by a new line:

```
string[] nums = table.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>(0).ToString()).ToArray();
TextBoxNums.Lines = nums;
```